# Automated SQL Backups using only FTP and HTTP

Tags: backup, ftp, mysql, automation

There are several hosting services hosting several websites with several frameworks (Wordpress, Joomla, ...).

Since I have neither SSH nor any backend access, I have a weekly schedule of

- uploading PhpMyAdmin using FTP
- Surfing to PhpMyAdmin
- Login (using the same credentials as the installed Framework)
- Download/Export Database
- remove PhpMyAdmin using FTP

I would like to partly automate this, I've already automated the FTP Upload/Download, but maybe there is a simpler "SQL Dumper" script thats more straight forward and easier to automate?

Comment: Write a script to query the data you need. Make it password protected so you don't have to delete it. Call it whenever you want to create a backup, save the result. Done.

Comment: If you are able to set up a cron job and call mysqldump from PHP it's pretty easy to set up a scheduled dump of a database and, optionally, mail it to yourself or simply leave it available on your site should you need it. As RalfFriedl said, you'll want to put the code and dump files in a password protected directory so they aren't visible to anyone but you. FWIW the 2 working lines I use in PHP to do dumps are: `$cmdline = "/usr/bin/mysqldump --host=$hn  --user $un -p$pw --databases $db --skip-extended-insert --quick --result-file=$bu_File";
exec($cmdline);`

Comment: The `$bu_File` variable has the full path to where the backup file is stored and it is of course within the protected directory. `$bu_File = '/home/virtualh/public_html/Private/DB-Backups/' . date("Ymd") . "-" . $db . ".sql";`. That way I can tell exactly what date the backup was made (I have other code that removes older backups keeping only 2 weeks worth on file).